# Tensor product of Representations of Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

If $(V_{1},\pi _{1})$  and $(V_{2},\pi _{2})$  are representations of a Lie algebra $ \mathfrak {g}$, then the tensor product of these representations is the map $\pi _{1} \otimes \pi _{2}:\mathfrak {g} \to \operatorname {End} (V_{1}\otimes V_{2})$ given by

$$   (\pi _{1} \otimes \pi _{2})(X) :=  \pi _{1}(X) \otimes I + I \otimes \pi _{2}(X)   $$

Is there a particular reason why not to define it in most naive way like for Lie groups as

$$ (\pi _{1} \otimes \pi _{2})(X) := \pi _{1}(X) \otimes \pi _{2}(X) $$

What would be in that case be violated? Or is the sole reason to to do it as in first case to make it functorial in the sense that $\pi: G \to \operatorname {GL} (V)$ induces $\pi: \mathfrak {g} \to \operatorname {End} (V)$ and in order to make the functor compatible with tensor products it should be defined as first case. Or is there a simpler reason involved why $ (\pi _{1} \otimes \pi _{2})(X) := \pi _{1}(X) \otimes \pi _{2}(X) $ is discarded?

Comment: What happens in your definition when you multiply $X$ by a scalar?

Comment: @mindfieldz: I see, the requirement on linearity of $ \pi _{1} \otimes \pi _{2}$ is in my definition violated. On the other hand to definite it in that way for tensor products of reps of Lie-group is fine, because there no liniarity condition like for Lie algebras is imposed? that's the point?

Comment: @JustusC Yes the key there is to note a Lie group rep has to be a group homomorphism while a Lie algebra rep has to be Lie algebra homomorphism. The former respects group multiplication while the latter has to respect linearity and the Lie bracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second definition just doesn't define a Lie algebra representation at all; a Lie algebra representation must in particular be a linear map, and what you've written down isn't linear.

Conceptually $(\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2)(X) = \pi_1(X) \otimes I + I \otimes \pi_2(X)$ is an expression of the product rule. Elements $X$ of a Lie algebra correspond to infinitesimal elements of a corresponding group $\exp(\varepsilon X) = I + \varepsilon X$, and when you tensor two such infinitesimal elements together you get

$$(I + \varepsilon \pi_1(X)) \otimes (I + \varepsilon \pi_2(X)) = I + \varepsilon \left( \pi_1(X) \otimes I + I \otimes \pi_2(X) \right).$$